# Jquery Append - Odd Behaviour

Tags: jquery, append

I have the following function:

```
function go_to(sec,name) {
    $("#lib_nav td:nth-child(2)").append('<span> &gt; <a style="cursor:pointer" OnClick="$(\'.content\')
                                 .html(\'<p>Loading</p>\')
                                 .load(\'_library_q.php?\',\'sec='+sec+'\')>'+name+'</a></span>');
    $('.content').html('<p>Loading</p>')
                         .load('_library_q.php?','sec='+sec);
}
```

Which is called by a script like

```
<div class="darkbox" style="cursor:pointer" OnClick="go_to(2,'Hello World');">
```

The problem is that, in the .append line, it only append a `<span> > </span>` and it completely skips over the  `<a>`. The second `.load` function works, however. Any thoughts?

Comment: HTML strings with inline event handlers are difficult to maintain and error prone due to wrong quotation marks etc. I suggest you create DOM elements and attach the event handler accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a closing double quote for your onclick handler:

```
function go_to(sec,name) {
    $("#lib_nav td:nth-child(2)").append('<span> &gt; <a style="cursor:pointer"    OnClick="$(\'.content\')
                                 .html(\'<p>Loading</p>\')
                                 .load(\'_library_q.php?\',\'sec='+sec+'\')">'+name+'</a>    </span>');
    $('.content').html('<p>Loading</p>')
                         .load('_library_q.php?','sec='+sec);
```

}

Comment: Thank you, it works! Darn jQuery was just being too smart on my and wouldn't break my page.